# JHipster + Angular + MongoDB + Docker: beginner question

Tags: jhipster

I would like to have some guidance about what is supposed to be the best development workflow with JHipster.

What I did expect:

- With one docker-compose command, I could up and run everything the project needs (in this case, MongoDB, Kafka, backend, etc.);
- When modifying front-end, saving the modified files, could fire livesync (`ng serve --watch`?).

What I did find:

- The one command option that I found (`docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up -d`), which I guess that depends of a `./mvnw package -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild` before, does not livesync and seems that is not compatible with the individual execution of front-end with `npm run start` - application started this way points to different backend's modules ports (?).

I have experience with Angular and MongoDB (and a little with Docker), but I'm super new to JHipster and am trying to understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development workflow, you should start the dependencies individually.  The `app.yml` will start the app's Docker image with the `prod` profile, useful for testing locally before deploying.

- Start Containers for [Mongo](https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#4) and [Kafka](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-kafka/)

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mongodb.yml up -d
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/kafka.yml up -d
```

- [Start the backend](https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#running-java-server)

`./mvnw`

- [Start frontend live-reload](https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#working-with-angular)

`npm start`

If Docker is not accessible on `localhost`, you may need to configure `application-dev.yml` to point to the Docker IP.